# How to fix 403 POST error in php and stripe

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, stripe-payments

I have two GCP virtual machines in different Enviornments one is in production environment and other one is in test environment,
in the TEST Environment I am getting 200 ok message on Stripe event which POST request using PHP , on the other hand I am getting 403 message on
Stripe event which POST request using PHP which is in production environment.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smuF14D6XWA81ivlaXp51hxgFNkSG9yC/view?usp=sharing  // Image of 200 ok message on test environment

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KD9w5CalCMSGm7Ys-B3HgmH1fZaw2Wpt/view?usp=sharing  // Image of 403 error on production

Note :- due to 403 error In production environment we are not getting payload data

" We are not getting data in $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');  and we are getting Payload is empty.
The versions of php and API used are correct.
allow_url_fopen is ON in php."

Difference in two vms:-

In Test environment the is vm is:-
1.PHP + Apache2 is installed ,
2. Not attached to any Loadbalancer ,
3.SSL is not configured ,
4.Cloud armour is not set

In production environment the vm is :-
1.PHP + Apache2 is installed ,
2. VM is Attached to the Loadbalancer ,
3.SSL is configured in apache2 ,
4.Cloud Armor is also set in Loadbalancer

so can anyone please tell the reasons I am getting 200 ok message on one machine and 403 on the other.

Comment: You've just posted your account id and signing secret to a public forum.

Comment: Are you using `express-sslify` for your production environment? To make sure the connection is establishing on https since your dev environment works on http (where you probably dont have that option enabled)

Comment: It could be anything; we need more information to help.  Does disabling Cloud Armor get things working?  Can you share your webhook handling code and let us know which line of code is producing the 403 response?  If you're not sure which specific line it is can you add logging code to determine the specific line?